# onLongClick called twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I registered onLongCLickListener for ImageVIew in onBindViewHolder method of my recycler adapter(maybe not best way to do it there).

```
         swipeBaseViewHolder.ava.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"longclick");
                }
            }
```

And when i checked logcat, i noticed longclick called twice on one long click on image.

Comment: You shouldnt do it there, recycling views algorithm is complex and might be calling it twice. Instead. register your listener during `getView()` method if your main view is a ListView.

Comment: Maybe you right, but its not the main reason of the problem.I forgot to mention that i use RecyclerSwipeAdapter from this lib  [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout). In others usual recycleradapters all work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was bug in android [Swipelayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) lib. One of pull requests  on github resolved this issue

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this answer. I had the _exact_ same problem. You probably saved me hours of debugging :)